# Verificar se o campo é nulo no java e mysql

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, jdbc, resultset

Como eu faço para verificar se o um campo do banco de dados está preenchido ou está nulo? Tem algum método do ResultSet que faz essa verificação?

No caso é um campo date.

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tarefas");
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
        while(result.next()) {
            Tarefa tarefa = new Tarefa();
            tarefa.setId(result.getLong(1));
            tarefa.setDescricao(result.getString(2));
            tarefa.setFinalizado(result.getBoolean(3));

            if(quero fazer a verificação aqui) {
                Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendario.setTime(result.getDate(4));//Ainda não sei se isso funciona
                tarefa.setDataFinalizacao(calendario);
            }
            lista.add(tarefa);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em java use:

```
String descricao = result.getString(2);

if (descricao == null) {
     //Nulo
} else {
     //Não nulo
}
```

Se você quer ignorar linhas que contenham uma coluna nula no mysql pode use `IS NOT NULL` assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Não sei o que eu fiz de errado que eu acho que eu tentei o primeiro, e não deu certo, agora com o seu auxilio foi.

Comment: @WelsonTeles as vezes pode ser que confundiu algo ou não havia recompilado, mas que bom que resolveu.

Comment: quanto a segunda solução não serveria para mim, ja que eu quero pegar todas as linhas, só nao conseguia tratar os campos nulos, valew